# Xamarin listView second click don't show item - Maybe this is a problem?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

I wrote two days ago about my problem with listView in Xamarin.Forms with RestApi client. Here is link [Xamarin listView second click don't show item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53598717/xamarin-listview-second-click-dont-show-item).

I put a lot of code because I couldn't find the error. It is possible that I noticed the problem?

I ModelViews I have code (ZasobyListContentPageViewModel.cs)

```
...
public DelegateCommand<UnivElement> ItemTappedCommand => _selItemCommand ??    (_selItemCommand = new DelegateCommand<UnivElement>(ShowMyDateDetails));

    private async void ShowMyDateDetails(UnivElement paramData)
    {
        var parameters = new NavigationParameters
        {
            {"myItem", paramData },
            {"title", paramData.C1 }
        };

        await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("ZasobDetailsContentPage", parameters);

    }
...
```

And in ZasobDetailContentPageViewModel.cs I have:

```
...
public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
{
    if (parameters.ContainsKey("myItem"))
    {
        UnivElemDetails = (UnivElement)parameters["myItem"];
    }
    if (parameters.ContainsKey("title"))
    {
        Title = (string)parameters["title"];
    }
}
...
```

I debugged aplication and I noticed that code

`await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("ZasobDetailsContentPage", parameters);`

in ZasobyListContentPageViewModel.cs is run every time you select a list item but code

```
public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
{
    if (parameters.ContainsKey("myItem"))
    {
        UnivElemDetails = (UnivElement)parameters["myItem"];
    }
    if (parameters.ContainsKey("title"))
    {
        Title = (string)parameters["title"];
    }
}
```

in ZasobDetailContentPageViewModel.cs is run only on the first click on the list element and varieble UnivElemDetails is binding with my xaml.

Can this be a problem? What do I have to do with it?

Thanks for every help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin listView second click don't show item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53598717/xamarin-listview-second-click-dont-show-item)

Comment: Ok ,you can test like this.`public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters){ Console.WriteLine("title=" + (string)parameters["title"] +"item="+(UnivElement)parameters["myItem"]); }` Make sure that the second click whether have data pass.

Comment: Thank you Jiang. I tested and I repaired the error. Thank you very much